# Scipy installation error when installing openai['embeddings'] dependencies with pip

Tags: python, pip, scipy, openai-api

When attempting to install openai['embeddings'] with pip, I receive an error when pip attempts to install the scipy dependency. I am trying to avoid using Conda, as I am much more familiar with pip. Please could you tell me how to fix this error?

I am running

- pyenv 2.3.14
- Python 3.10.6
- pipenv 2023.3.20

on MacOSX.

The error output is below:

```
Installing openai[embeddings]...
...
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.4/42.4 MB 15.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

[36m  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.0.1
      Source dir:
/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-install-lo2paia0/scipy_737b9929d1564228920272097a8b29c5
      Build dir:
/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-install-lo2paia0/scipy_737b9929d1564228920272097a8b29c5/.mesonpy-hg3s
h936/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 650.9
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 650.9
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.33)
      Host machine cpu family: aarch64
      Host machine cpu: aarch64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: YES
      Library m found: YES
      Fortran compiler for the host machine: gfortran (gcc 12.2.0 "GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0")
      Fortran linker for the host machine: gfortran ld64 650.9
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
      Checking if "-Wl,--version-script" : links: NO
      Program cython found: YES
(/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-build-env-qh0mtg4o/overlay/bin/cython)
      Program python found: YES (/Users/tom/.local/share/virtualenvs/skills-9YAMSSbX/bin/python)
      Found pkg-config: /opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
      Program pythran found: YES
(/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-build-env-qh0mtg4o/overlay/bin/pythran)
      Run-time dependency threads found: YES
      Library npymath found: YES
      Library npyrandom found: YES
      Did not find CMake 'cmake'
      Found CMake: NO
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and framework)

      ../../scipy/meson.build:134:0: ERROR: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not found, tried pkgconfig and framework

      A full log can be found at
/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-install-lo2paia0/scipy_737b9929d1564228920272097a8b29c5/.mesonpy-hg3s
h936/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      + meson setup --prefix=/Users/tom/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6
/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-install-lo2paia0/scipy_737b9929d1564228920272097a8b29c5
/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-install-lo2paia0/scipy_737b9929d1564228920272097a8b29c5/.mesonpy-hg3s
h936/build
--native-file=/private/var/folders/tr/rsy8rmfd40zczm17pl8wyv5w0000gn/T/pip-install-lo2paia0/scipy_737b9929d1564228920272097a8b29c5
/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2


  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Comment: If you're on macos 11 you'll need to update to Macos 12 to pip install a wheel. There are no pre built wheels for that os version due to various issues.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
```

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2394